# Setting maxLength of input field in react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield, maxlength, use-form

I have multiple fields on different pages all controlled from a single page and using material ui textfield. I have to set different maxLength for different fields.

I found inputProps={{maxLength: 10}} , but this allows only 1 fixed value, I need a way to set different values depending on requirement.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Make your maxLength a state, so you can conditionally set it:

```
const [dynamicLength, setDynamicLength] = useState(10);
```

```
<TextField 
    inputProps={{
       maxLength: dynamicLength
    }}
/>
```

Check code on sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/textfield-h95ti

Comment: not sure it needs a state. A variable might be enough...

Comment: Yes, a variable is enough and worked for me. Thanks for the contribution @Diogo M.F.